# Dynamic slider using PHP/MySQL &

Tags: php, jquery, nivo-slider

I have box for dynamic images and desc slider using [nivoslider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/). Now I have big problem -> my PHP code is:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<?php 
$featured = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM featured WHERE order > 0 ORDER BY order ASC");
$count_featured = mysql_num_rows($featured);
            
if ($count_featured < 1) { echo "error data" }
while ($swcms = mysql_fetch_assoc($featured)) { ?>
   <img width="500" height="170" src="<?php echo "$swcms[image]"; ?>" title="#<?PHP echo "$swcms[id]"; ?>" alt="" border="" />
   <div id="<?PHP echo "$swcms[id]"; ?>" class="nivo-html-caption"><?PHP echo "$swcms[desc]"; ?> </div>
<?php $c++; }?>    
</div>
```

This Worked 100% But in firebug I see many GET undefined request after each slide:
[image]

I found the problem; nivoslider worked with this method for show images/desc (caption):

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<img src="..." title="#id" />
</div>
<div id="id" class="nivo-html-caption"></div>
```

And my PHP loop is:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<img src="..." title="#id" />
<div id="id" class="nivo-html-caption"></div>
</div>
```

How do I fix this PHP code for nivoslider loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<?php 
$featured = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM featured WHERE order > 0 ORDER BY order ASC");
$count_featured = mysql_num_rows($featured);
$captions = '';
if ($count_featured < 1) { echo "error data" }
while ($swcms = mysql_fetch_assoc($featured)) { ?>
   <img width="500" height="170" src="<?php echo "$swcms[image]"; ?>" title="#<?PHP echo "$swcms[id]"; ?>" alt="" border="" />
   <?php $captions .= '<div id="' . $swcms[id] .'" class="nivo-html-caption"' . $swcms[desc] .'</div>'; ?>
<?php $c++; }?>    
</div>
<?php echo $captions; ?>
```